# How to remove certain numeric values from a dataset in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a data set for which I am trying to extract gene names, however they have a numeric value infront of them (their ID) also in the row which I need to remove:

```
data = pd.read_csv("genes_person1.csv")
```

I read in my data which has this input:

```
Column 1
153 ADRB1
3486 IGFBP3
9531 BAG3
9612 NCOR2
```

I have been trying to get this output:

```
ADRB1
IGFBP3
BAG3
NCOR2
```

I've looked into answers from similar questions, like using slices, .replace, rstrip, but this either hasn't done anything or removes numbers which are a part of my gene name which I need to keep. How can I remove the numbers at the start of each row?

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: Split on the space and take the second component.

Comment: Thank you both for your commentd. I will try to split that way now, and yes I am using pandas, I import my data with pd_read.csv, I will add this in to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Column 1": ["153 ADRB1", "3486 IGFBP3", "9531 BAG3", "9612 NCOR2"]})
print(df["Column 1"].str.split().str[1])
```

**Output:**

```
0     ADRB1
1    IGFBP3
2      BAG3
3     NCOR2
Name: Column 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for this I am going to try it now. This seems like it would work best for me as I have 80 genes to go through, would there be a quick way for me to obtain all 80 genes to have in quotes for the pd.DataFrame line? Or can it only be done manually?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand

Comment: for the ["153 ADRB1", "3486 IGFBP3", "9531 BAG3", "9612 NCOR2"] I have 80 more genes to add into those [ ], can I only do this manually? Apologies for any confusion from me I am very new to python

Comment: No you do not have to do it manually....I used `pd.Dataframe` as an example. You only need `print( data["Column 1"].str.split().str[1] )`

Answer (score 2):

```
genename = "153 ADRB1"
print(genename.split(" ")[1])
```

Comment: Uh, Why reversed?

Comment: In case id is empty

Comment: But on the other hand, you might want an error if id is empty, I think I'll remove the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the dataset in to columns by splitting the csv file based on space and take the second column, as below:

`datatemp = pd.read_csv("genes_person1.csv", sep=' ')
data = datatemp.iloc[:, 1]`